# Is there a way to prevent iTunes from asking me to update my iPhone's carrier settings?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I don't sync my iPhone with my work computer.  I just plug it in to charge it.  Is there a way to prevent it from prompting me every time to update the phone's carrier settings?:

[image]

I have un-checked iTunes' "Check for new software updates automatically" setting, but it still asks for me to update the carrier settings.

Comment: Get a charge only cable, there easy to find, type "charge only lightning cable" in the Amazon search box.

Comment: Do those exist for a 4S? I don't have lightning on my 4S. Aside from that, is there a software solution?

Comment: They do exist but are hard to find in stock anywhere anymore.  A better search would be "charge only USB adapter" which is basically a piggy back usb plug that only passes the voltage pins and not the data pair.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm the message about updating your carrier settings is not an IOS upgrade. It is a tiny little file that your carrier (EG AT&T, Verizon, etc.) places on your phone to keep it up to date with their network.

Let it check and apply it, it takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: But it asks me every day - even multiple times a day (because since it's an old phone, the battery's not so great and I tend to keep it plugged in). Every time I plug it in, it asks me. It asks me when I plug it in at home too, but I'll usually let it check then - but it still asks me at home frequently.

Comment: If you let it check and it either downloads a new settings file or does not find one there may be an issue with your phone. I'd be tempted to back it up, wipe it and restore see if that fixes it. Failing that call your carrier's tech support and see what they have to say.

Comment: Came here to hopefully stop this annoyance. It may be a tiny file from carrier, but it is iTunes that is doing the popup. Can someone answer how to stop iTunes from asking this? Whether or not I accept the update, it still asks every time iTunes connects to my iPhone. Sorry, but this is not the answer!

Comment: Have you backed up, wiped and restored your phone, as suggested? That simple procedure fixes a LOT of iPhone issues. I would try that first. After that, I don't know as I have never seen that error. Which is why this is a comment and not an answer.